# Parallel processing end of execution in project reactor

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I have the following reactive stream that gets data from a 3rd party API and then populates a hashMap in parallel.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> tempHashMap = new HashMap<>();
        Flux.fromIterable(cList)
                .parallel(20)
                .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(cId -> {
                    List<String> lb = api.getlb(p,cId);
                   
                    if(!lb.isEmpty()) {
                        tempHashMap.put(cId, lb);
                    }
                    return Flux.just(tempHashMap);
                })
                
                .sequential()
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                .doOnNext(hashMap-> lb = processMap(hashMap)
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    log.error("Error while getting list of lb : {} ", throwable.getMessage());
                    return;
                })
                .subscribe();
```

I had expected processMap() method would be called just once after all the parallel processing is completed, with the addition of sequential(). However, it is being called on every parallel thread. Can someone help me understand why?

Comment: Several things, parallel process should be used for cpu-hevy tasks, not I/O work. flatMap will most likely be faster here. Also you should be using a parallel scheduler when using parallelFlux. Also dont use a state (like you are doing by placing a hashmap outside the stream) a flux is not a loop. Use `collectMap` if you wish to create a hashmap out of all the stuff you get from the api. But i would remove the parallel it makes no sense here. Also all you scheduling (boundedelastic and single) also makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give more details on why you say parallel doesn't make sense here. The reason I added parallel processing is to make the entire process faster. api.getlb() is a time consuming process and I wanted the execution to be parallel rather than sequential for each item in cList

Comment: i have answered this several times before, please use google to read up on the difference between async work and parallel work here is one answer i have written. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972395/1840146 this is general computing knowledge not associated to any framework or programming language. A slow i/o call will always be a slow i/o call.

Comment: I am fairly new to reactive programming so please bear with me incase my questions are repetitive. I added this code based on my research on parallel processing in reactive system. Initially without parallel this process was taking 15 mins, that is when I read about parallel and added that feature which reduced the process time to 4 mins. I understand it uses CPU resources, but I didn't see another way to make this process faster.

Comment: Please understand when im writing ”most likely” that does not mean ”always”. I have no idea whats behind the `api.get`. If you are a beginner you should do more research before asking on stack overflow as questions get repeated and most this is answered in the official reactor docs. The reactor documentation goes through things like `collectMap` async/vs parallel, when to use schedulers, and how to use them etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did do research on async/vs parallel, schedulers and that's how I came up with this solution. My apologies,  I asked the question here when I couldn't find anything, I should have researched more on collectMap

Comment: @perplexedDev try to call `processMap` inside of a `doOnComplete` instead of a `doOnNext`. But @Toerktumlare has a good point here that you shouldn't modify external state from reactive streams, especially because of thread safety concerns.